# The definition of compactly supported boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

In Chi-wang Shu's article *Discontinuous Galerkin Methods: General Approach and Stability*, "compactly supported boundary conditions" is mentioned in **Proposition 3.2** and **Proposition 3.3**. I don't know its exact definition and after searching for it through Bing, I fail to get any useful information from the Internet.

I guess that "compact supported boundary conditions" may mean that for $t\in [0,T]$, the solution of the PDE
$$u_t+f(u)_x=0 \ (x,t)\in[0,1]\times [0,T]$$
equals to 0 on the boundary, namely
$$u(0,t)=0$$and
$$u(1,t)=0.$$
I am not sure of my guess, as I have not find any information from published books or papers supporting it.